# how can I split array by delimiter

Tags: php, arrays, fopen, explode

I got string that I split using 'explode()'.But I need some more steps to do.I have to split that array output few more times by delimiter.

The txt file's contents look like

```
 Question1|opt1,opt2,opt3;Question2|opt1,opt2,opt3;question3|opt1,opt2,opt3;Question4|opt1,opt2,opt3;
```

Please have a look at the code

```
$open=fopen("mydata.txt","r+");
  while(!feof($open)){
     $see=fgets($open);
     $exp=explode(";",$see);
     //$exp1=explode("|",$exp);
     //$exp2=explode(",",$exp1);

     $vaq = "</br> ".$imp[0];
     echo $vaq;

    }
fclose($open);
```

what I need is to echo in following format

```
Question1
Opt1
Opt2
Opt3

Question2
Opt1
Opt2
Opt3

.......
.......
.......
```

I know 'explode()' split string and output array.but even after that tried to see the result.It gives me error.

Look forward for expert assistance.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = file_get_contents('mydata.txt');
$data = preg_split('/[\|,;]/', $str);
echo join("\n<br>", $data);
```

Code assumes that non of `QuestionN`, `OptN` have symbols `|`, `,` and `;` inside.

If you want to separate all the things

```
$blocks = explode(';', file_get_contents('mydata.txt'));
foreach($blocks as $block)
{
    list($question, $opts) = explode('|', $block);
    $opts = explode(',', $opts);

    // do whatever you wanted to do
    var_dump($question);
    var_dump($opts);
}
```

Comment: I don't think it needs the <br>, but otherwise good answer +1

Comment: @cheery Thanks a lot.It worked.+10000 and Lots of Love

Comment: @l'L'l just copied what TS had for the output )

Comment: @cheery do you know any other way to get that same output?I need the options(Opt1,Opt2,Opt3) to be radio button.It is not possible by the way you mentioned,I think

Comment: @cheery Thanks a lot.You are very friendly and helpful.